# Change value of yaml file with shellskript

Tags: bash, shell, sed, yaml

I am writing a script with which the user can, for example, change an IP in a `yaml` file by entering it via the keyboard. But I have problems with the `sed` command, can anybody help me with this. I have only found commands that replace a string with a string incorporated in the command `sed`.

Yaml-file

```
network:
    address: [00.000.0.00]
```

Script

```
echo "Please enter the desired IP address:" 
read input
ip="$input"
sed??????????????????
```

Comment: Don't change input file when you get response already

Answer (score 0):

With `yq` (same as `jq` but meant for `YAML`):

```
yq '.network.computer.address = "[1.1.1.1]"' file.yaml 
{
  "network": {
    "address": "[1.1.1.1]"
  }
}
```

This is the proper tool for this usage. Both python and go versions works here.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use yk

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(address: *)\[[^][]+\]/\1[1.1.1.1]/' file.yaml
```

or

```
sed 's/\(address: *\)\[.*/\1[1.1.1.1]/' file.yaml
```

### Output

```
network:
   computer:
       name: xxxx
       address: [1.1.1.1]
```

Add `-i` to edit *in place*

Comment: Thanks for your help. That means, could I also use my variable $ip instead of [1.1.1.1].

Answer (score 0):

With your given input, maybe something like this:

```
read -rp 'Please enter the described IP address: ' input

##: Validate input here, if it is not empty
##: If it is indeed an format that is valid 
##: for your requirement and so on...

sed -E "/network:/{N;/address: \[00\.000\.0\.00\]/s/[[:digit:].]{1,}/$input/;}" file.yaml
```